# ¿como mapear otro puerto aun cotenedor existente?

Tags: linux, docker

estoy empezando a usar docker, creé un contenedor, al correrlo le mapeé el puerto 8080:80, por que solo necesitaba un server apache, el lío está en que luego le instalé webmin y este corre en el puerto 10000, ¿como puedo añadir el mapeo 10000:10000 al contenerdor que ya está activo?, de ante mano gracias por su ayúda.

```html
server@server:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
b8a73e695137        452a96d81c30        "/bin/bash"         2 hours ago         Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   testserver
```

---

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: deseas cambiar el puerto de ese contenedor que esta corriendo?

Comment: No amigo, lo que deseo es añadirle otro puerto al que ya esta mapeado, gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos formas, si estas corriendo docker con **docker run** con **-p** puedes mapear todos los puertos que quieras, ejemplo:
**docker run -p 8080:80 -p 10000:10000**

Si estar corriendo desde un docker-file:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  nginx:
      image: nginx:latest          
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
        - "10000:10000"
```

Tienes que detener el container y volverlo a crear.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jaime.

Comment: Gracias, Oscar por marcar la respuesta como "Aceptada", muchos no lo hacen y esto ayuda a otros usuarios a ver cual fue la respuesta que te dio solucion. Saludos